# How to return data from the database query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement `ExportToPDF()` action method in my ASP.NET Core MVC web app.

When action method `ExportToPDF()` is called, it should export all data from the database. But only header row is shown, and the actual data from the database is not shown at all.

I'm not sure how to correctly implement this action method, and what I'm doing wrong here?

My simplified code:

```
public class EmployeeCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double NetSalary { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public double GrossSalary { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeCategoryController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
 
    public EmployeeCategoryController(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        Context = _context;
    }
 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6).ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult ExportToPDF()
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();

        var query = employees.AsQueryable().Take(6)
                             .Select(employee => new
                                                 {
                                                     employee.Id, employee.Name, employee.LastName, 
                                                     employee.Address, employee.GrossSalary, employee.NetSalary 
                                                 }).ToList();

        // Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Table start.
        sb.Append("<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;'>");

        // Building the Header row.
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Id</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Name</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>LastName</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Address</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>NetSalary</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>GrossSalary</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>NetSalary</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>GrossSalary</th>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");

        // Building the Data rows.
        query.ForEach(employee =>
                      {
                          sb.Append("<tr>");

                          foreach (var propertyInfo in employee.GetType().GetProperties())
                          {
                              sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid #ccc'>");
                              sb.Append(propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
                              sb.Append("</td>");
                          }

                          sb.Append("</tr>");
                      });

        // Table end.
        sb.Append("</table>");

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())))
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
            pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(stream, pdfDocument);

            pdfDocument.Close();

            return File(byteArrayOutputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "EmployeeList.pdf");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your code is far from minimal. Use a table with only one column to minimize the code. Also, please format your code properly. It's hard to read with all the broken indentation

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank you for your suggestion.I tried my best, to keep the code clean and minimal as possible. Please see fixed code.

Comment: I would try to see what is at query. Set a breakpoint and have a look in the watch window. Do you have get data from database? Then next check the sb.ToString() is the output? does the string contains more then the headers?

Comment: @tire0011 Thank you for suggestion. This is really good suggestions. I will definitely have that in mind, when I next time face similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error I found here:

```
 var employees = new List<Employee>();

 var query = employees.AsQueryable().Take(6).Select(employee => new
             {
                 employee.Id, employee.Name, employee.LastName, employee.Address, employee.GrossSalary, employee.NetSalary
             }).ToList();
```

You should change code to

```
Context.Employees.Take(6).Select(m => new Employee{ Id =m.Id, 
                        Name=m.Name
                        ...
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the issue. I refactored code a little bit. You can check the code below. Again, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

`Refactored Code:`

```
public class EmployeeCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double NetSalary { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public double GrossSalary { get; set; }

}

public class EmployeeCategoryController : Controller
{

    private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
 
    public EmployeeCategoryController(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        Context = _context;
    }
 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6).ToList());
    }


        [HttpPost]
        public FileResult ExportToPDF()
        {

            

            // Fixed query
            var query = Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6).Select(m => new EmployeeCategory
            {
              Id = m.Id,
              Name = m.Name,
              LastName = m.LastName,
              Address = m.Address,
              NetSalary = m.NetSalary,
              GrossSalary = m.GrossSalary,
            }).ToList();
        


            

            // Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Table start.
            sb.Append("<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;'>");

            // Building the Header row.
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Id</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Name</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>LastName</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Address</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>NetSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>GrossSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>NetSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>GrossSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");


            // Building the Data rows.
            query.ForEach(employee =>
            {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (var propertyInfo in employee.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
            sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid #ccc'>");
            sb.Append(propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
            sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            });





            // Table end.
            sb.Append("</table>");

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())))
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
                pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(stream, pdfDocument);
                pdfDocument.Close();
                return File(byteArrayOutputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "EmployeeList.pdf");
            }
        }
}
```